# S4 wifi not connecting

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I have a Samsung S4 and when trying to connect to wifi it comes up with a "sign into wifi network" notification. When I click on the notification it takes me into the browser but the login page does not load. During this time, for about 30 seconds, my phone does receive emails and WhatsApp messages, etc., but after 30 seconds the connection is lost with no page loaded.

This is a wifi network that I used previously about 2 days ago and normally I login to it with out having to go into a login page.

I have tried re-booting the modem, forgetting the network, and re- booting my phone. 
Can anyone help please?

Comment: Maybe it's the configuration of their gateway. Can anybody else in the area use that wifi? Can you connect with another device? What about other networks? It sounds to me that it's not your device at all that's having the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your wifi settings disable scanning always available then turn off and turn on the wifi